# Name of the property that certain matrix powers approach the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation, matrix-decomposition

For a proof I'm looking for the name (or proof) of the property that:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}(BAB^{-1})^t = I, \left(\text{ where in my case: } A = \begin{bmatrix}I_n & 0\\0&-I_m \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

With $A,B,I\in\mathbb{R}^{(n+m)\times(n+m)}$

Comment: Is it such that since $B$ is non-singular that $BAB^{-1}$ is a matrix which eigenvalues are equal to the diagonal of $A$, but how does this imply that matrix powers approach identity?

Comment: If you write $A^2=I$ then it is said to be an involution.

Comment: Let $BAB^{-1}=C$, so $\lim C^t=I$. I think this implies $C=I$. (Notice that this is true for numbers: if $z^t\to1$, then $z=1$.) For let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $C$. Then $\lambda^t$ is an eigenvalue of $C^t$, so $\lambda^t\to1$, so $\lambda=1$, so $C$ is similar to a matrix with ones on the diagonal and possibly just above the diagonal (and zeros everywhere else), but if there are any nonzero entries above the diagonal  then they increase as $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only matrix $A$ that satisfies the given condition is the identity matrix.

Consider the Jordan form $J$ of $A$ over $\mathbb C$. The given condition implies that $\lim_{k\to\infty}J^k=I$, we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda^k=1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$. Hence all eigenvalues of $A$ or $J$ are equal to $1$. It follows that $J$ has no nontrivial Jordan block, otherwise $J^k$ would possess a super-diagonal entry whose value is $k$, contradicting the fact that $J^k$ converges to $I$. Thus $J=I$, i.e. $A=I$.